# The two standard voices in Mexican music

Tags: genre-characteristics, vocal-styles, nasal-singing

Answering [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8448/genre-with-nasal-digitally-processed-sound) about nasal tones in popular music made me wonder.  I've frequently heard songs from Mexico that pair two singers, one with a noticeably more nasal sound. For example:

[Aerolina Carrilo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIyqRdrHodE) - T3rcer Elemento

[El Chuchumbe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m19fpUTfJDY) - Las Cafeteras (this group features two such pairs, one male and one female)

[Un Poco Loco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yg8116aeD7E) (from *Coco*)

I've heard this too often for me to think it's just a coincidence.  Is there a name for these roles?  Does anyone know the history of it?

Comment: I think the "lead" is referred to as the [pregonero](http://www.conjuntojardin.com/son_jarocho/), other info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preg%C3%B3n)